Laravel Reverb isn't functioning on the wss:// protocol on a Rocky Linux production server
I'm deploying a Laravel application with Reverb on a production server, aiming to establish a secure connection. In my .env file, I've configured Reverb with the following settings:
REVERB_APP_ID=123456
REVERB_APP_KEY=random_key
REVERB_APP_SECRET=random_secret
REVERB_HOST=server_host
REVERB_PORT=443
REVERB_SCHEME=https

However, when attempting to connect from the client-side via WebSocket (wss://...), I encounter the following error:
WebSocket connection to 'wss://...' failed
I tried adding path in reverb.php but did not help.
'options' => [
    'tls' => [
    'local_cert' => 'path',
    'local_pk' => 'path',
 ],
 ],

What could be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it to establish a successful WebSocket connection in my Laravel application with Reverb on a production server? Any insights or troubleshooting steps would be greatly appreciated.

same problem for me .. i spent all the day without success .. can you solve you problem ?

anyone got success running laravel reverb on aws lightsail lamp?
